# Bash string compression

Tags: macos, bash

I'd like to know how I can compress a string into fewer characters using a shell script. The goal is to take a Mac's serial number and MAC address then compress those values into a 14 character string. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to hear if anyone has any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by compressing here?  An example would be good.

Comment: How many characters are in Mac serial numbers? For MAC addresses, you could easily encrypt from 12 characters to 6 by mapping each 2 character permutation [0-F][0-F] into a single character on the extended 256 character ascii set.

Comment: A MAC address may be represented as a string of characters, but it is actually a number, usually represented as six groups of two hex digits. You can represent that number much more compactly by using a larger base, such as base 64, however, to the machine, the most compact form will probably be a long integer.

Comment: For example can I "compress" "c02gt255dbt2 a4b297fe3e55b1c2" (serial# + MAC without) into something that is 14 characters long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is way too vague to result in a detailed answer.

Given your restriction of a 14 character string output, you won't be able to use "real" compression (like `zip`), due to the overhead. This leaves you with simple algorithms, like RLE or bit concatenation.

If by "string" you mean *"printable string"*, i.e. only about 62 or so values are usable in a character (depending on the exact printable set you choose), then you have an additional space constraint.

A handy trick you could use with the MAC address part is, since it belongs to an Apple device, you already know that the first three values (`AA:BB:CC`) are [one of 297 combinations](http://standards.ieee.org/cgi-bin/ouisearch?apple), so you could save 6 characters (plus 2 for the colons) worth of information into 2+ characters (depending on your output character set, see above).
The remaining three MAC address values are base-16 (0-9, A-F), so you could "compress" this information slightly as well.

A similar analysis can be done for the Mac serial number (which values can it take? how much space can be saved?).

The effort to do this in bash would be disproportionate though. I'd highly recommend a C (or other programming language) approach.

Comment: "AA:BB:CC" is a placeholder, a MAC address is sometimes referred to as "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF", regardless of actual values. For the actual possible values of AA:BB:CC, click the link in the text.

Comment: Woops, completely misinterpreted what you meant originally, +1.

Answer (score 0):

## Cheating answer

Get someone at Apple to give you access to the database I'm assuming they have which matches devices' serial numbers to MAC addresses. Then you can just store the MAC address and look it up in the database whenever you need the serial number. The 64-bit MAC address can easily be stored in 12 characters with standard base64 encoding.

## Frustrating answer

You have to make some unreliable assumptions just to make this approachable. You can fix the assumptions later, but I don't know if it would still fit in 14 characters. Personally, I have no idea why you want to save space by reprocessing the serial and MAC numbers, but here's how I'd start.

### Simplifying assumptions

- Apple will never use MAC address prefixes beyond the 297 combinations mentioned in Sir Athos' answer.
- The "new" Mac serial number format in [this article from
  2010](http://www.macrumors.com/2010/04/16/apple-tweaks-serial-number-format-with-new-macbook-pro/) is the only format Apple has used or ever will use.

### Core concepts of encoding

- You're taking something which could have `n` possible values and you're converting it into something else with `n` possible values.
- There may be gaps in the original's possible values, such as if Apple cancels building a manufacturing plant after already assigning it a location code.
- There may be gaps in your encoded form's possible values, perhaps in anticipation of Apple doing things that would fill the gaps.

### Abstract integer encoding

1. Break apart the serial number into groups as "PPP Y W SSS CCCC" (like the article describes)
2. Make groups for the first 3 bytes and last 5 bytes of the MAC address.
3. Translate each group into a number from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the number of possible values for something in the group. As far as I can tell from the article, the values are `n_P=36^3`, `n_Y=20`, `n_W=27`, `n_S=3^3`, and `n_C=36^4`. The first 3 MAC bytes has 297 values and the last 5 have 2^(8*5)=2^40 values.
4. Set a variable, `i`, to the value of the first group's number.
5. For each remaining group's number, multiply `i` by the number of values possible for the group, and then add the number to `i`.

### Base `n` encoding

1. Make a list of `n` characters that you want to use in your final output.
2. Print the character in your list at index `i%n`.
3. Subtract the modulus from the integer encoding and divide by `n`.
4. Repeat 1 and 2 until the integer becomes 0.

### Result

This results in a total of `36^3 * 20 * 27 * 36 * 7 * 297 * 2^40 ~= 2 * 10^24` combinations. If you let `n=64` for a custom base64 encoding
 (without any padding characters), then you can barely fit that into `ceiling(log(2 * 10^24) / log(64)) = 14` characters. If you use all 95 printable ASCII characters, then you can fit it into `ceiling(log(2 * 10^24) / log(95)) = 13` characters.

### Fixing the assumptions

If you're trying to build something that uses this and are determined to make it work, here's what you need to do to make it solid, along with some tips.

- Do the same analysis on every other serial number format you may care about. You might want to see if there's any redundant information between the serial and MAC numbers.
- Figure out a way to detect between serial number formats. Adding an extra thing at the end of the abstract number encoding can enable you to track which version it uses.
- Think long and careful about the format you're making. It's a lot easier to make changes before you're stuck with backwards compatibility.
- If you can, use a language that's well suited for mapping between values, doing a lot of arithmetic, and handling big numbers. You may be able to do it in Bash, but it'd probably be easier in, say, Python.